# Saving text to File where address is relative to what is saved

Tags: vb.net, text, save

so I have a form with a multitude of textboxes (txtUsername, txtPassword, txtAddress.......)

and im after saving to a .txt file which is called based on what txtUsername is
so, C:\Example\Example\Example\"txtUsername".txt

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    If System.IO.File.Exists("\ ..\ ..\Resources\Users\<txtUsername>.txt")
    ) Then
        MsgBox("File Already Exists)")
    Else
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("\ ..\ ..\Resources\Users\<txtUsername>.txt" 
        objWriter.Write(txtsave.Text)
        objWriter.Close()
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You know there wont be a "Resources" folder when deployed (and it looks like one too few `\ ..`) and even if you create it, the app may not have access to it.  The `ProgramData` and `Users` folders were designed for this sort of thing and are less error prone than relative paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

created a variable called path then used 
 `System.IO.StreamWriter(path)` where`path = "\ ..\ ..\Resources\Users\" + txtUsername.Text + ".txt"`

Comment: Note, that the idiomatic way to concatenate strings in VB.Net is to use the concatenation operator which is `&` in VB.Net and not `+`.  However, you should use `Path.Combine` rather than concatenation for creating paths.